# Light Javascript table filter, displaying results with minimum character input?

Tags: javascript

I am using this script to filter a table:

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tIuBL

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get this script to only display search results when a certain number of characters are entered.  Right now, it will search if any input is put into the filter box and I'm trying to get it to show results only if a minimum of three characters have been entered.

```
var limits = {
minChars: 3
}
```

I know I should probably be using jQuery for this, but this is what I am committed to at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using your code. We basically 'ignore' the value until it reaches a certain number of characters the store it and use that variable...

```
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;
    var _value;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
      _input = e.target;
      _value = _input.value;
      if (_input.value.length < 3) {
        _value = '';
      }
      ...
    }

    function _filter(row) {
      var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(),
        val = _value.toLowerCase();
      row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    ...

})(document);
```

Comment: when you press backspace, the reverse should works!! but not working in your code

Comment: still it is not working properly, when you press the backspace button.. try this use case.. press joh, now john should display, now delete h and o, now only words with j should appear, but in you case alfread also displayed. please check and let me know

Comment: @RajaSekar OP is asking to **"show results only if a minimum of three characters have been entered."** The answer I provided does exactly this. It requires a minimum of 3 characters to be entered for it to filter results.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Beautiful.  Thank you, good sir!

Answer (score 0):

Working code. Let me know if you need any clarification.

```js
 (function(document) {
 'use strict';

 var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

  var _input;

  function _onInputEvent(e) {
   console.log(e);
   _input = e.target;
   var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
   Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
    Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
     if(e.code === "Backspace"){
      Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _defaultfilter);
     }else{
      Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
     }
     
    });
   });
  }

  function _defaultfilter(row) {
   console.log(row);
   var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
   row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
  }

  function _filter(row) {
   console.log(row);
   var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
   console.log(_input.value);
   if(val.length >= 3){
    row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
   }
  }

  return {
   init: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
     input.addEventListener("keyup", _onInputEvent);
    });
   }
  };
 })(Array.prototype);

 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
   LightTableFilter.init();
  }
 });

})(document);
```

```html
<section class="container">

 <h2>Light Javascript Table Filter</h2>

 <input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filter">

 <table class="order-table table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
    <td>0123456789</td>
    <td>99</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Jane Vanda</td>
    <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
    <td>9876543210</td>
    <td>349</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
    <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
    <td>6754328901</td>
    <td>199</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

</section>
```